# Eclipse grinds to a halt when building workspace

Tags: performance, eclipse

This is a bit of a vague question because, frankly, I don't even know where to begin diagnosing the issue.  My eclipse (Galileo) installation grinds to a complete halt when it's building the workspace -- to the point where I can't even type.  I know the Android SDK I have installed is a major culprit because I can watch the memory usage go through the roof (through the built-in heap monitor) when the Android SDK content loader starts up.  Every time I save a file though, the program just stops.  The message at the bottom of the screen says

> Building workspace (74%)

and sits there for about 30 or so seconds before completing and returning the performance to normal.  I have a few other plugins installed (Maven, SVN, etc) but I'm assuming the main issue is Android.  Has anybody had similar issues or any luck correcting this sort of problem?

If there's anymore information you think would be helpful, just let me know...I didn't want to do a core dump on this question...

I'm running it on Windows 7 64-bit for what it's worth.

Comment: Here is something I found on Stack Overflow: [Link to thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

> Building workspace gets stuck at 99%
>   If Eclipse hangs while "building workspace", try killing any running adb processes in the background. There actually seem to be a variety of possible causes, but when using the ADT Eclipse plugins, this might work.

See here: http://Android-sdk.wikispaces.com/Building+workspace+stuck+at+99%25

Comment: Kill adb process worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try un-checking auto-build: Project > Build Automatically

This will prevent a build whenever you save a file.

Comment: Possible workaround, he will be able to save, but it still will hang on build time.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Eclipse at the command line with the `-clean` argument.